# mysql Fill missing month in range of two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fill month missing in this query, and set the missing one at 0 elements :)

```
SELECT MONTH(timestamp), YEAR(timestamp), count(*) as Total
FROM dialogs
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2023-01-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp);
```

the result is this:

```
7,2022,354
8,2022,4715
9,2022,2712
10,2022,1740
```

but i'm expect something like:

```
6,2022,0 // <--- missing month in table
7,2022,354
8,2022,4715
9,2022,2712
10,2022,1740
11,2022,0 // <--- missing month in table
```

and so on..

Comment: The result isent from the query. the start date in the query is '2021-09-01'

Comment: @BerndBuffen, yes from 9,2021,0 ;  10,2021,0 ; 11,2021,0 .....etc

Comment: Review https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224182/generate-dates-between-date-ranges-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

you will need a full calendar

```
WITH recursive years AS (
select 2010 as yr
union all
select yr + 1 
from years
where yr <= 2030)
, months AS (
select 1 as mon
union all
select mon + 1 
from months
where mon <= 12) 
SELECT cal.yr, cal.mon, ifnull(tbl.total,0) total
FROM (SELECT MONTH(timestamp) mon, YEAR(timestamp) yr, count(*) as Total
FROM dialogs
GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp)) tbl
right join ( select * from years join months ) cal ON cal.mon=tbl.mon and    cal.yr=tbl.yr
WHERE cal.yr BETWEEN 2019 AND 2023 
order by 1,2;
```